# npm oracledb installation fails

Tags: angular, npm, certificate

I setup node.js and npm for angular cli and I was also able to go through the angular tutorial.

Then I wanted to install the npm oracledb module with this command: `npm install oracledb` but it fails.

I have installed python 2.7.14 and also set my npmrc configs to use a proxy.

```
proxy=http://user:pass@company.com:8080/
https-proxy=http://user:pass@company.com:8080/
strict-ssl=false
registry=http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

this is the result I get when installing:

```
d:\Users\user\Documents\GitHub\angular-start-app>npm install oracledb

> oracledb@1.13.1 install d:\Users\user\Documents\GitHub\angular-start-app\node_modules\oracledb
> node-gyp rebuild


d:\Users\user\Documents\GitHub\angular-start-app\node_modules\oracledb>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "D:\U
sers\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild
 )  else (node "" rebuild )
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: unable to verify the first certificate
gyp ERR! stack     at Error (native)
gyp ERR! stack     at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (_tls_wrap.js:1092:38)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:185:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:610:8)
gyp ERR! stack     at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:440:38)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "D:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\no
de_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd d:\Users\user\Documents\GitHub\angular-start-app\node_modules\oracledb
gyp ERR! node -v v6.11.4
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.2 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any
"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! oracledb@1.13.1 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the oracledb@1.13.1 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

The installation fails because of some certificate. I have also updated npm with: npm install --global update

Does anybody know why?

Answer (score 1):

Go to http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winx64soft-089540.html
You will need an oracle account for this, creating one is free.

Download the Basic Package (All files required to run OCI, OCCI, and JDBC-OCI applications):
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winx64soft-089540.html

Unzip this to a folder:
C:\oracle\instantclient
Add this to your path environment variable.

Download the Development and Runtime Package (sdk)
You will need these header files for node-gyp to run
SDK Package - Additional header files and an example makefile for developing Oracle applications with Instant Client: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winx64soft-089540.html

Unzip this to a sdk folder inside the instantclient folder:
C:\oracle\instantclient\sdk

Create these environment variables:
OCI_LIB_DIR C:\oracle\instantclient\sdk\lib\msvc
OCI_INC_DIR C:\oracle\instantclient\sdk\include
This could also be done with a bindings.gyp file if you do not want to create the environment variables but I haven't tested this method out

You may also need to install Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 found here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads 
and windows build tools like this `npm install --global --production windows-build-tools`

now running `npm install oracledb` should work

Comment: These instructions are for node-oracledb v1, but for v2 there are prebuilt binaries available so you don't need the header files or to set OCI_*_DIR.  What is still a problem is installing via proxies that need authentication, see https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/pull/919

Answer (score -1):

- Use node-oracledb 2 which has pre-built binaries.  General install instructions are at https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/INSTALL.html
- Because your proxies need authentication but node-oracledb support for them is still pending (see https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/pull/919) you will want to install node-oracledb using https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/INSTALL.html#manualextraction